# amp-bind not working inside to change an element's class inside AMP Story

Tags: amp-html, amp-list, amp-bind

I have created a sidebar inside an AMP Story Page.

Inside the sidebar i have a menu with links and sub menus. I am trying to add an "active" class to submenu items when their parent is clicked using this code

```
<div class="caret" on="tap:AMP.setState({sidebar.openMenu: 1})">
```

And grabbing the toggle in the submenu item with

```
<ul [class]="sidebar.openMenu ? 'active' : ''" class="subMenu">
```

The problem is that when i tap the parent Menu item, a console error

AMP.setState is not whitelisted

appears and nothing changes.

How can i whitelist the AMP.setState action inside the AMP Story Page sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `amp-bind` to create a multi-level `amp-sidebar` navigation, [use AMP actions and events instead.](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/)